# jenkins on demand slaves windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent, ondemand

The on-demand slaves are being created successfully from Jenkins. The first build on the slave is successful but the subsequent builds are fails. The restart of the slave or restart of the wimrc services allows the build to proceed again.

The tcpdump shows no errors. Can't figure out what the issue is. Looks like issues Jenkins communicating with on demand slaves using wimrc.

Has anybody faced similar issue? 
The on-demand slaves are windows slave

Comment: forgot to mention on-demand slaves are windows slave

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the "MaxMemoryPerShellMB" parameter of the Winrm. This was set to too low. So when the npm or git was doing a checkout it was running out this memory in the Winrm shell.

I have increased to 1GB and its working fine now